# Is this possible to display week in FullCalendar starting with given week start date?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Parameter `firstDay` doesn't seem to work with `type: 'agendaWeek'` or `dateAlignment: 'week'`

I am trying to display the current week from given `firstDay` (say 2) but I cannot do that.

Duration parameter doesn't work, firstDay doesn't work, nothing work.

Except setting visibleRange: {
                        start: '2017-10-03',
                        end: '2017-10-08'
                    }
However, if I hardcode the current week it wouldn't work the next week, and I want it work whenever week I open it to display the current week starting with given week start date

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following solution:

```
var x = firstDay;
_FiveDaysWeek: {
                type: 'agendaWeek',
                hiddenDays: [ (x + 5) % 7, (x + 6) % 7 ]
            }
```

Propery `hiddenDays` works like a charm, for week starting from Tuesday I can set hiddenDays to [ 0, 1], for week starting from Wednesday I can set hiddenDays to [ 1, 2 ], for week starting from Monday I can set hiddenDays to [ 0, 6 ], for week starting on Sunday I can set hiddenDays to [ 5, 6 ].